# What does it mean to be "sound"?

Tags: terminology, random-oracle-model, fiat-shamir, soundness

I've been reading this in many places and I still don't properly understand what it means to be "sound". As an example of what I am asking for:

> The Fiat-Shamir transfrom is **sound** in the Random Oracle Model (ROM), where hash functions are assumed to behave as Random Oracles.

I know that being in the ROM means that hash functions are thought to be trully random functions and the Fiat-Shamir is a technique to transform interactive $\Sigma$-protocols to non-interactive. So what that means?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An [interactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system) or non-interactive protocol is said to be sound for a language $\mathcal{L}$ if it is "hard" for a (malicious) prover $\textsf{P}$ to convince a verifier $\textsf{V}$ of a statement $I\not\in\mathcal{L}$. Depending on how "hard" it actually is for $\textsf{P}$ to cheat, we either get a (interactive or non-interactive) *proof* system (when $\textsf{P}$ is computationally unbounded) or an *argument* system (when $\textsf{P}$ is computationally bounded).

*The [Fiat-Shamir transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic)* compiles an interactive protocol into a non-interactive protocol by, roughly-speaking, replacing the verifier $\textsf{V}$ with a hash function $H$. To be more precise, the prover computes -- by itself -- the $i$-th verifier message $\beta_i$ by hashing the transcript so far (which consists of the statement $I$, the prover messages $\alpha_i$s from the previous rounds and the previous values of $\beta_i$s): see the figure below (which is taken from [here](https://research-explorer.app.ist.ac.at/download/7896/7897/2020_Thesis_Kamath.pdf)). In the [random oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) (ROM), the hash function $H$ is modelled as a [random oracle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial), i.e., a random function accesible to all parties via an oracle.

[image]

The Fiat-Shamir transform is said to be "sound", if it "preserves" the soundness of the interactive protocol being applied to. That is, the non-interactive protocol $(\textsf{P}_{FS},\textsf{V}_{FS})$ that results by applying the Fiat-Shamir transform to a interactive protocol $(\textsf{P},\textsf{V})$ is also sound. We say that the Fiat-Shamir transform is sound in the ROM if the above holds when $H$ is modelled as a random oracle.

*When is the Fiat-Shamir transform sound?* It is known to be sound in the ROM when applied to constant-round interactive *proof systems* [PS00]. In particular, we end up with a non-interactive *argument system*. One of the most common examples of this is the [Schnorr signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature), which is obtained by applying the Fiat-Shamir transfom to the Schnorr identification scheme.

On the other hand, we know of certain [counterexamples](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72460/problem-with-fiat-shamir-on-poly-round-interactive-protocol/72469#72469) where the transform is "unsound" even in the ROM. I'd finish by adding that there has been a lot of exciting recent works that have aimed at proving the soundness of the Fiat-Shamir transform in the standard model (i.e., without random oracles): see [C+19,PS19] and reference related to them.

[C+19]: Canetti et al. *[Fiat-Shamir from Simpler Assumptions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1004)*, STOC'19

[PS00]: Pointcheval and Stern, *[Security arguments for digital signatures and blind signatures](http://www.di.ens.fr/users/pointche/Documents/Papers/2000_joc.pdf)*, JoC, 2000.

[PS19]: Peikert and Sheihan *[Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge for NP from (Plain) LWE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/158).*, Crypto'19